# -webkit-mask-image - using SVG as mask

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use SVG to create a mask for an HTML element. For browser compatibility reasons (I could be wrong), I'm applying the SVG image as a data uri:

```
#shape { 
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background:blue;
   -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'><rect fill='white' x='90' y='50' width='70' height='50'/><rect fill='white' x='150' y='150' width='70' height='50'/></svg>");
   -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The SVG itself looks like:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>
    <rect fill='white' x='90' y='50' width='70' height='50'/>
    <rect fill='white' x='150' y='150' width='70' height='50'/>
</svg>
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/whL48/

You can see the original large blue rectangle has been masked to show two smaller ones.

What I'm trying to achieve is the inverse of this - the large blue rectangle is visible, with two smaller ones cut out of it, but my SVG chops aren't great.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the colours of your SVG.  You'll also need to add a white rectangle to fill the background of the SVG.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>
    <rect fill='white' width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <rect fill='black' x='90' y='50' width='70' height='50'/>
    <rect fill='black' x='150' y='150' width='70' height='50'/>
</svg>
```